# Has the primary benefit of statins in reducing early deaths never been fully tested in comparative trials?

Tags: medical-science, pharmaceutical, medications, drug-development

Ben Goldacre, in his sustained critique of the way the pharmaceutical industry and its regulators fall far from the standards of reliable evidence (*[Bad Pharma](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bad-Pharma-companies-mislead-patients/dp/0007350740)*), makes an astounding claim (p193 of the paperback, my emphasis):

> Trials have been done comparing statins against placebo, and these have shown they save lives rather well. Trials have also compared one statin to another: but these all use cholesterol as  a surrogate outcome. **Nobody has ever compared the statins against each other to measure which is best at preventing death.** This is a truly staggering oversignt when you consider that tens of millions of people have taken these drugs and for many, many years.

There are two pieces of background information that should provide the background required to see why this is an astounding claim.

The first is that statins, designed to reduce cholesterol levels (for a more technical description read the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statin)), are very widely prescribed and make a huge amount of money for the pharmaceutical industry. It has even been suggested that they should be widely used in healthy populations (see [BBC news story](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-18091708) for background and discussion). They have been the single largest cost category of prescribed drugs in the NHS ([2007 BBC story](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/programmes/politics_show/7192271.stm)). Total worldwide sales [are estimated](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/health/healthnews/8267876/Statins-the-drug-firms-goldmine.html) to exceed $35 billion.

The second is that proxy or surrogate outcomes are not a reliable measure of the effectiveness of a drug. Surrogate outcomes are usually something that is easy or quick to measure (in the case of statins, cholesterol levels). They are used to judge results in trials of drugs because the ultimate goals (the primary outcome) are often harder to measure and take longer to measure (for statins, cardiovascular events and death). The trouble is surrogate outcomes are often misleading. For example, it was long thought that drugs that reduce irregular heart rhythm were good for people who have survived heart attacks as they often have irregular rhythm. But this was shown to be wrong by the famous CAST trial ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_Arrhythmia_Suppression_Trial), [review article](http://circ.ahajournals.org/content/91/1/245.full)): it turned out that drugs reducing irregular rhythm (the proxy) cause significantly more heart attack deaths (the primary outcome the drugs were intended to prevent).

So, while I would normally just take Ben Goldacre on trust as an expert, this claim is so bold it deserves separate skeptical analysis. He claims there have never been proper trials of one of the biggest classes of drugs that measures what they are intended to achieve.

So *has there never been a trial comparing statins using the primary outcome of fewer deaths from cardiovascular events?*

Comment: Excellent example of questioning a sceptic. Though I have to mention the caveat that I’m unsure what answer you’d find sufficient. An exhaustive review of Pubmed articles mentioning statins? Oh my …

Comment: @KonradRudolph Fair point. But in the case of this claim I might be prepared to accept *independent* confirmation from other experts. A full meta-analysis of trials would be nice, but I suspect there isn't one. We can dream, though!

Comment: I find it to be a plausible claim.  In clinical trials, we attempt to find proximal biomarkers that predict the health outcomes of interest and allow us to conduct a study with reasonable time and expense.  Because high cholesterol does not predictably kill people in a short time frame, any study would take a long time, longer than many academic researcher's careers.  And the variability in causes of death that you see in a decades long study would mean you'd need a huge sample size.

Comment: lower cholesterol reducing the risk of a heart attack is well researched and well documented, I don't think maintaining regular heat rhythm ever had a similar body of evidence, which makes their comparison somewhat misleading.

Comment: @Ryathal The CAST trial isn't the only example where the proxy measure is misleading. But I think it *is* a fair example given the knowledge at the time. The [ALLHAT](http://qjmed.oxfordjournals.org/content/96/10/771.full)  results for doxazosin (perfectly good at lowering blood pressure, but *many* more heart attacks) would be another where the proxy is seriously misleading.

Comment: @Ryathal And, the key issue is not whether * cholesterol* is associated with cardiovascular events, but whether different statins have *other* effects that might alter their risk profile. To know which is best we *must have* that other information.

Comment: Nothing wrong with questioning something in a best-selling book. Even though Ben Goldacre is a (presumably) fully-credentialed, licensed, practicing medical doctor, he made this claim in a non-specialist book, and not, apparently, as the result of research followed up with peer-review. On the other hand, I'm of similar mind as  @KonradRudolph because it seems unlikely you'll find anything to definitively prove Goldacre wrong. Even though he may, in fact, be very wrong about this! I'm rather cynical about people who write popular non-fiction, admittedly.

Answer (score 7):

There has not been any statin vs statin comparisons, but there was a comparison of different dosages of the same statin. 10,001 patients were either assigned to treatment with either 10 mg of atorvastatin or 80 mg of atorvastatin. The primary end point was the occurrence of a first major cardiovascular event, defined as death from CHD, nonfatal non-procedure-related myocardial infarction, resuscitation after cardiac arrest, or fatal or nonfatal stroke.  The results showed that 80 mg was superior. [1]

> A primary event occurred in 434 patients (8.7 percent) receiving 80 mg
>   of atorvastatin, as compared with 548 patients (10.9 percent)
>   receiving 10 mg of atorvastatin, representing an absolute reduction in
>   the rate of major cardiovascular events of 2.2 percent and a 22
>   percent relative reduction in risk (hazard ratio, 0.78; 95 percent
>   confidence interval, 0.69 to 0.89; P<0.001).

and the conclusion:

> Intensive lipid-lowering therapy with 80 mg of atorvastatin per day in
>   patients with stable CHD provides significant clinical benefit beyond
>   that afforded by treatment with 10 mg of atorvastatin per day. This
>   occurred with a greater incidence of elevated aminotransferase levels.

This shows, ceteris paribus, that with respect to LDL-c, lower is better.

Ben Goldacre is concerned that should there be just a 2% difference between the different drugs, there could be vast numbers of lives not saved due to choosing the wrong statin. [2]

A systematic review study protocol 2010 looked at these issues and confirmed [3]

> This is because of the fact that most randomized clinical trials have
>   not tested different statins head-­‐to-­‐head. Additionally, almost
>   all of the meta-­‐analyses ‘lumped’ all statins together as one
>   intervention

And they state also

> Combination  of  direct  and  indirect  evidence:  Methodological 
>   advances  in  statistical  synthesis  approaches, called mixed
>   treatment comparisons  (also known as network meta-analyses), 
>   facilitate the  combination  of  direct  and  indirect  evidence  by 
>   incorporating  both  direct  (when  statins  are compared  to  each 
>   other  within  a  trial)  and  indirect  comparisons  (when  statins 
>   are  compared between trials with a common comparator treatment, which
>   is often placebo).

So, they claim that statistic methods make head to head comparisons unnecessary.

**The answer to the question is, so far there have not been any head to head trials with cardiovascular endpoints.**

[1] LaRosa JC, Grundy SM, Waters DD, Shear C, Barter P, Fruchart JC, Gotto AM, Greten H, Kastelein JJ, Shepherd J, Wenger NK, . [Intensive lipid lowering with atorvastatin in patients with stable coronary disease.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15755765) N. Engl. J. Med. 2005 Apr;352(14):1425-35. doi: 10.1056/NEJMoa050461. PubMed PMID: 15755765.

[2] http://www.forbes.com/sites/johnlamattina/2013/03/01/do-we-really-need-head-to-head-comparison-trials-with-statins-to-improve-cardiac-health/

[3] [COMPARATIVE CLINICAL EFFICACY OF STATINS: A SYSTEMATIC REVIEW AND MIXED TREATMENT COMPARISON](http://www.lse.ac.uk/LSEHealthAndSocialCare/pdf/HNaciProtocol.pdf) 2010

Comment: Does a comparison of two dosages of the same drug count as a comparison against other drugs?  Or is there a typo?

Comment: @Bobson The explanation as to why a same drug comparison is used is given in the answer.  No typo.

Comment: You start out saying `Actually there has been a statin vs statin comparison`, but conclude `so far there have not been any head to head trials`.  I suggested an edit which clears it up.

Comment: @Bobson I intended it to be a little confusing so that the reader would think more about whether head to head trials were actually necessary.  Oh well ...